# How to substitute exact number of semi-colon from string using REGEX?

Tags: python, regex

I need to remove all occurrences of single semi-colon, but retain double occurrences.

Input:

```
poop,hello\/# what;up,\wor;;ld; yolo| s|ag"j"d\nhdhf,\;;
```

Expected Output:

```
poop hello    what up  wor;;ld  yolo| s|ag"j"d hdhf  ;;
```

So, I am able to remove everything except the occurrence of a single semi-colon.

```
a=re.sub(r'[^\w|\d|(;;)|\|"]'," ",a)
```

where `a` is the string displayed at the top.

But it gives me:

```
poop hello    what;up  wor;;ld; yolo| s|ag"j"d hdhf  ;;
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: You can trick: `your_string.replace(';;', '@@').replace(";", "").replace('@@', ';;')`

Comment: Perfect, works like a charm.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead and a negative lookbehind:

```
>>> re.sub(r'[^\w\d;|"]|(?<!;);(?!;)'," ",a)
'poop hello   what up  wor;;ld  yolo| s|ag"j"d nhdhf  ;;'
```

Comment: Yeah, was planning on this. This reduces # of steps, but increases complexity. Understanding wise.

Comment: No need to escape `|` inside a character class.

Comment: @stribizhev - I tried to clean that part up; looks like I missed a bit. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
s.replace(";;","$").replace(";"," ").replace("$",";;")
```

replacing `;;` to `$`, than replace `;` into space than replacing back `;;`.

Comment: Yeah, perfect, like @Valijon commented.